# Thread termination (again...)

Tags: multithreading, delphi

When i stop thread 'srch_slave_thread' with setting the termination flag to true, (srch_slave_thread.terminate) freeing the thread stops at the 'inherited' line in the destructor, why? Is it a WaitFor that it hangs on? If i comment out 'inherited' in the destructor, the thread stops and free itself.

After taking out 'inherited' and debuging the code: Why the thread jumps into the DoTerminate method after calling the destructor?

Thank You.

```
Tsrch_slave_thread = class(TThread)   
private
  FSW: TStopWatch;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  SimpleEvent: TSimpleEvent;
  procedure DoTerminate; override;
  ...
  constructor Create; 
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

Creating an event obj. in the constructor >>

```
constructor Tsrch_slave_thread.create;
begin
  inherited create(true);   
  Fsw := TStopWatch.Create;
  SimpleEvent := TSimpleEvent.Create;
end;
```

Jumps here after calling destructor? >>

```
procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.DoTerminate;
begin
  inherited;
  self.simpleEvent.SetEvent; 
end;
```

Thread hangs at inherited in the destructor >>

```
destructor Tsrch_slave_thread.destroy;
begin
  self.SimpleEvent.free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Create the thread here >>

```
function TMaster.th_slvsearch_start: integer; 
begin
  if not Assigned( Fslave_search_thread ) then begin
    Fslave_search_thread := TFslave_search_thread.create;
    ... 
  end
  else begin  
    ...
    exit;
  end;  
  with Fslave_search_thread do
  begin    
    master := self;  
    master_HWND := self.fMsgHandlerHWND;
    FreeOnTerminate := false;
    OnTerminate := slvsrch_termination;
    start;         
  end;
end;
```

Stoping the thread starts here >>

```
procedure TMaster.th_slvsearch_stop;
begin
  Fslave_search_thread.Terminate; 
end;
```

Thread .Execute >>

```
procedure Tsrch_slave_thread.Execute;
var
  text_orig: string;
  activesearch: integer;
begin
  FSW.Start;
  while not terminated do begin
    activesearch := master.CMD_LISTCNT; 
    //stopper refresh
    synchronize(procedure begin         
        with self.master do
          Fmasternode.text := FmasterDat.MstrName + ' (' + floattostr(Fsw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000) + 'sec - Searching)';
    end);
    if (SimpleEvent.WaitFor(2000) <> wrTimeOut) or (activesearch <> 1) then break;  
  end;
  FSW.Stop;  
end;
```

OnTerminate event handler >>

```
procedure TMaster.slvsrch_termination(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned( Fslave_search_thread ) then
  begin
    self.FLastSearchTime := Fslave_search_thread.FSW.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
    Fslave_search_thread.Free; 
    Fslave_search_thread := nil;
    self.Factive_slv_search := 0;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: *"Why the thread jumps into the DoTerminate method after calling the destructor ?"* Because someone should say the thread to terminate and if it's not explicitly you, it is the destructor which sets the termination flag.

Comment: @TLama, yes but i set the flag with srch_slave_thread.terminate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `Free` on the thread object from its `OnTerminate` event handler. That alone is a mistake because you cannot free an object whilst it is firing an event, because when the event returns you are now executing code in a object that has been destroyed.

But that's not your immediate problem. You've deadlocked the thread because of the call to `WaitFor` in `TThread.Destroy`. The thread cannot finish because it is waiting on itself. The call stack on the thread looks like this:

```
Synchronize(CallOnTerminate)
DoTerminate
ThreadProc
```

So the thread is waiting on the main thread to finish executing `CallOnTerminate`. Over on the main thread, inside your `OnTerminate` handler is the call to `Free`. Which in turn leads to a call to `WaitFor`. Consequently the main thread is waiting for the thread to finish. That's your classic deadlock. Thread A waiting on thread B, and thread B waiting on thread A.

The moral of the story: never call `Free` on a thread inside its `OnTerminate` event handler.

The solution is probably to set `FreeOnTerminate` to `True` and in the `OnTerminate` handler set `Fslave_search_thread` to `nil`.

Comment: Its not the first time i make this mistake, but hope it was the last. Thank You.

Comment: Now my problem is, that if i close the application, some AV generated.

The thread's obj reference is a field of another object (TMaster). When i close the application, i free all the masters in a cycle. In TMaster's destructor i set the thread's termination flag (if the thread was assigned before). Whats wrong with this?

Comment: OK. Well, I guess you make an SSCCE, and post a new question.